# can't connect to azure file service REST api by python

Tags: rest, azure, python-requests, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I want to access my file service by python Request, guided by the [list shares page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-shares), I'm new to REST and python Request.
my input is

```
headers= {'x-ms-date': '2018-04-17 06:22:15.181620', 'Authorization': 'SharedKey zedongstorageaccount:codecodecodeFiTzubX9tvC3G3PcDYzR2cX/TMjkOu4JhsvQffS+xTDDBQ==', 'x-ms-version': '2017-07-29'}
url = 'https://zedongstorageaccount.file.core.windows.net/?comp=list'
r=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
```

But get error, the output of r.content:

```
b'\xef\xbb\xbf<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.\nRequestId:ef98f282-f01a-0042-3e24-d62397000000\nTime:2018-04-17T08:16:21.9635335Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>The Date header in the request is incorrect.</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>'
```

I have also try the header `{'x-ms-date': '2018-04-17 06:22:15.181620', 'Authorization': 'SharedKey zedongnewstorageaccount:NJYYtabOIj5D1R+xb0PpmXrjCldf6NA6oLkYReAKFiTzubX9tvC3G3PcDYzR2cX/TMjkOu4JhsvQffS+xTDDBQ==', 'x-ms-version': '2017-07-29'}`, because i don't know if the `Authorization` and `account` in the same line. I also tried many version of `x-ms-version`.
But there all the 400 or 403 respond.

I have read the [Authentication for the Azure Storage Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authentication-for-the-azure-storage-services) but confused.

Where is the error? And is there case I can learn to build my app by Azure REST API?(I use the keyword to google, all the pages are about build REST API and azure official docs)

Comment: Are you using account key in the `Authorization` header?

Comment: yes, account storage key. Does it wrong? What should I use?

Comment: Yes, it is incorrect. You will actually need to compute the authorisation header steps for which is outlined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authentication-for-the-azure-storage-services. I'm just curious as to why you're not using Python SDK for Azure Storage instead of using REST API directly?

Comment: Gaurav is right, why not use Python SDK instead of calling REST API directly?  https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python

Comment: I thought REST is easier to Python SDK in error. After listening your words, I will try Python SDK now.

Comment: And it there any case I can learn to build my app by Python SDK? I'm newbie with this.

Comment: @张泽栋 you have samples which are available in Azure Storage Python SDK GitHub repo https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/tree/master/samples/file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also recommend to use Python SDK but for educational purposes:

```py
import requests
import datetime
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

storage_account_name = 'teststorageaccount'
storage_account_key = 'D4x6YChpyfqWk9a.......'
api_version = '2016-05-31'
request_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')

string_params = {
    'verb': 'GET',
    'Content-Encoding': '',
    'Content-Language': '',
    'Content-Length': '',
    'Content-MD5': '',
    'Content-Type': '',
    'Date': '',
    'If-Modified-Since': '',
    'If-Match': '',
    'If-None-Match': '',
    'If-Unmodified-Since': '',
    'Range': '',
    'CanonicalizedHeaders': 'x-ms-date:' + request_time + '\nx-ms-version:' + api_version + '\n',
    'CanonicalizedResource': '/' + storage_account_name + '/\ncomp:list'
}

string_to_sign = (string_params['verb'] + '\n' 
                  + string_params['Content-Encoding'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Content-Language'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Content-Length'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Content-MD5'] + '\n' 
                  + string_params['Content-Type'] + '\n' 
                  + string_params['Date'] + '\n' 
                  + string_params['If-Modified-Since'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['If-Match'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['If-None-Match'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['If-Unmodified-Since'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Range'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['CanonicalizedHeaders']
                  + string_params['CanonicalizedResource'])

signed_string = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(base64.b64decode(storage_account_key), msg=string_to_sign.encode('utf-8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()).decode()

headers = {
    'x-ms-date' : request_time,
    'x-ms-version' : api_version,
    'Authorization' : ('SharedKey ' + storage_account_name + ':' + signed_string)
}

url = ('https://' + storage_account_name + '.file.core.windows.net/?comp=list')

r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)

print(r.content)
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><EnumerationResults ServiceEndpoint="https://teststorageaccount.file.core.windows.net/"><Shares><Share><Name>myfileshare</Name><Properties><Last-Modified>Tue, 17 Apr 2018 13:43:00 GMT</Last-Modified><Etag>"0x8D5A46922CA8BDA"</Etag><Quota>10</Quota></Properties></Share></Shares><NextMarker /></EnumerationResults>
```

Comment: I recommand  that you could regenerate the account key if  it is the real key.

Comment: @TomSun I have regenerated key and put fake name of storage account from the beggining, it was for better demonstration but thank you for care!