# Azure Blob PUT Rest api - Getting error "Signature fields not well formed"

Tags: python, azure, rest, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to simply upload a new blob to an Azure Storage container using Python Requests module but I'm getting the error **Signature fields not well formed**. What am I missing here?

```
import requests

file_name = "test.txt"

account = "<account_name>"
container = "<container_name>"
blob = "<blob_name>"
key = "sp=rwdlacupiytfx&st=2023-07-10T15:59:34Z&se=2023-12-10T23:59:34Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=<sig>"

file = open(file_name, "rb")

url = f"https://{account}.blob.core.windows.net/{container}/{blob}/{file_name}?{key}"
print(url)
headers = {'x-ms-version': '2020-10-02', 'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob'}

test_response = requests.put(url, data = file, headers = headers)

if test_response.ok:

    print("Upload completed successfully!")
    print(test_response.text)

else:
    print("Something went wrong!")
    print(test_response.text)
```

Error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:a0bf7a23-d01e-0073-0b7c-e59eea000000
Time:2023-09-12T13:28:03.2249045Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature fields not well formed.</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>
```

I obtained the SAS from the properties panel in *Azure Blob Storage Explorer*:

[image]

Comment: possibly an encoding issue on the `key`.  it also looks like the `PUT` docs say you don't need the `filename` path parameter.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob?tabs=azure-ad#request

`https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm getting the error **Signature fields not well-formed**. What am I missing here?

The error **“Signature fields not well-formed,”** indicates that there’s an issue with the format of the Shared Access Signature (SAS) token you’re using in the URL.

You can fetch an SAS-token from the portal.

***Portal -> your-storage-account -> shared access signature -> check the required permission -> copy the SAS token.***

**Portal:**

[image]

I tried with the below code and was able to upload the blob to storage.

**Code:**

```
import requests

file_name = "path/to/file.txt"

account = "<storage_name>"
container = "<container_name>"
blob = "test3465.txt"
sas_token = "<SAS_token>"  # Replace Your SAS token (excluding "?")

url = f"https://{account}.blob.core.windows.net/{container}/{blob}/{file_name}?{sas_token}"
print(url)

headers = {'x-ms-version': '2020-10-02', 'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob'}

with open(file_name, "rb") as file:
    test_response = requests.put(url, data=file, headers=headers)

if test_response.ok:
    print("Upload completed successfully!")
    print(test_response.text)
else:
    print("Something went wrong!")
    print(test_response.text)
```

**Output:**

```
 https://venkat678.blob.core.windows.net/test/test3465.txt/./test3465.txt?sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=co&sp=rwdlacupiytfx&se=2023-09-12T23:00:16Z&st=2023-09-12T15:00:16Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxxxxx
 Upload completed successfully!
```

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I don't have access to Azure Portal in order to generate a new SAS Token (probably that one was a bit old). Today they create an access key (instead of SAS Token), how can I use that?

Comment: To upload files to Azure blob storage with access key. you can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52839744/put-request-to-azure-storage-with-shared-key-authorization