# Python requests.get() for Azure blob

Tags: python, azure, python-requests, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to download blobs from Azure storage, and it would be preferred to me to use Python's `requests.get()`. If I try it with `get_blob_to_path()` from `azure`, it works, but not with `requests.get()`.

I use it as follows:

```
requests.get('https://<account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container_name>/<blob_name>')
```

I have also tried to just copy the whole URL from Azure Storage Explorer.

I get the following error from one account:

```
gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

and the following result (not displayed as an error) from another account:

```
<Response [404]>
```

What can cause this error / `<Response [404]>` and how to fix it? Is it some issues with permissions for connections through `requests.get()`?

Answer (score 3):

The error is due to you did not specify the permission to access blob storage.

Besides change the public access level to container or blob(**screenshot as below**) as @Martin mentioned in his post, you have the other 2 ways for the permission issue.

[image]

**Method 1**:You can generate a SAS URL for the blob. Nav to azure portal -> click the "..." symbol of blob you want to download -> select Generate SAS. After the SAS URL generated, you can use the SAS URL for blob downloading. The screenshot below shows how to generate SAS URL:

[image]

Then you can write code like below:

```
#use the SAS URL
r = requests.get('https://yy3.blob.core.windows.net/aa1/w2.JPG?xxxx')
open("d:\\temp\\mytest222.jpg","wb").write(r.content)
```

**Method 2**:Please take use of [Get Blob rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob), and the sample code below is working for me.

```
import requests
import datetime
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

storage_account_name = 'xxxx'
storage_account_key = 'xxxxx'
blob_name = 'your_blob_name,like w2.jpg, note it is case sensitive'
container_name='the container name'
api_version = '2018-03-28'
request_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')

string_params = {
    'verb': 'GET',
    'Content-Encoding': '',
    'Content-Language': '',
    'Content-Length': '',
    'Content-MD5': '',
    'Content-Type': '',
    'Date': '',
    'If-Modified-Since': '',
    'If-Match': '',
    'If-None-Match': '',
    'If-Unmodified-Since': '',
    'Range': '',
    'CanonicalizedHeaders': 'x-ms-date:' + request_time + '\nx-ms-version:' + api_version + '\n',
    'CanonicalizedResource': '/' + storage_account_name + '/'+container_name + '/' + blob_name
}

string_to_sign = (string_params['verb'] + '\n' 
                  + string_params['Content-Encoding'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Content-Language'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Content-Length'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Content-MD5'] + '\n' 
                  + string_params['Content-Type'] + '\n' 
                  + string_params['Date'] + '\n' 
                  + string_params['If-Modified-Since'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['If-Match'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['If-None-Match'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['If-Unmodified-Since'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Range'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['CanonicalizedHeaders']
                  + string_params['CanonicalizedResource'])

signed_string = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(base64.b64decode(storage_account_key), msg=string_to_sign.encode('utf-8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()).decode()

headers = {
    'x-ms-date' : request_time,
    'x-ms-version' : api_version,
    'Authorization' : ('SharedKey ' + storage_account_name + ':' + signed_string)
}

url = ('https://' + storage_account_name + '.blob.core.windows.net/'+container_name+'/'+blob_name)

r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)

#specify where to download and the new file name
open("d:\\temp\\mytest111.jpg","wb").write(r.content)

print("ok")
```

Comment: For the first method, is there an automatic generation of SAS URLs? I will have to download hundreds of blobs, it is definitely not a good idea for me to press buttons manually. Or for the second method, is it possible to construct Authorization header without account key (with a connection string instead)? I do not have required permissions for making the storage public / see the primary/secondary keys.

Comment: @Valeria, for method 1, do you have permission to create an account-level SAS via ui(by nav to azure portal -> your storage account->left pane -> Shared access signature)? if yes, then you can use this account level SAS for all the blobs download. For method 2, if you have a connection string(if I understand correctly), the account key of course includes in the connection string(the connection string should be DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xx;AccountKey=xxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net).

Comment: For method 2: I am not sure about details since I am new to Azure, but I was told it is a "connection string with SAS". Basically, it is of this format: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1. It has `SharedAccessSignature` (`sv`, `ss`, `sig` etc.) and `BlobEndpoint`. I tried to use `sig` as `signed_string` from the code, but I get the same error as in the beginning (`[Errno -2] Name or service not known`).

Comment: can you try put this url("https://your_storage_account.blob.core.windows.net/your_container/your_blob? + your_connection_string") in requests.get(url)? to see if any error occurs? or if some error occurs, do you mind email this connection string to me?

Comment: @Valeria, do you have any more issues?

Comment: @IvanYang Very helpful. For Get File (REST API), can I use your method 2 without changes?

Comment: I changed "url = ('https://' + storage_account_name + '.blob.core.windows.net/'+container_name+'/'+blob_name)" to "url = ('https://' + storage_account_name + '.file.core.windows.net/'+ file_path)" like described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49874783/cant-connect-to-azure-file-service-rest-api-by-python. It worked, thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

You are not authenticating this request, so I have made a public blob storage container to test this, and it works so I think its a permission's issue. Is the blob storage public as shown here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-access-to-resources

Here is my code, test and see if it works:

```
import requests
req = requests.get('https://publicstoragefallout.blob.core.windows.net/publiccont/icon.png')
open('icon.png', 'wb').write(req.content)
```

Note that it also works if you use http instead of https.

Hope this helped!