# Connect to Azure Storage Emulator via REST API & Python

Tags: python, azure, rest, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-emulator

I cannot connect to the Azure Storage Emulator using REST & Python.

I can using the Python SDK

I want to try and make some REST calls to better understand the functionality, to compare speeds and look at using in cloud functions to reduce my image size.

I've tried to use the code found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49881347/9201100, however when using with the emulator i'm constantly returned AuthenticationFailed

I found a recent C# project on github https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-dotnet-rest-api-with-auth. If i include the emulator account_name and account_key it runs perfectly fine.

So i modified the code a little bit updating the api_version = '2017-04-17' and the canonicalized resource to match but still no good.

please help

```
import datetime
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

storage_account_name = "devstoreaccount1"
storage_account_key = "Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw=="
api_version = '2017-04-17'
request_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')

string_params = {
    'verb': 'GET',
    'Content-Encoding': '',
    'Content-Language': '',
    'Content-Length': '',
    'Content-MD5': '',
    'Content-Type': '',
    'Date': '',
    'If-Modified-Since': '',
    'If-Match': '',
    'If-None-Match': '',
    'If-Unmodified-Since': '',
    'Range': '',
    'CanonicalizedHeaders': 'x-ms-date:' + request_time + '\nx-ms-version:' + api_version + '\n',
    'CanonicalizedResource': '/' + storage_account_name + '/'  + storage_account_name + '\ncomp=list'
}

string_to_sign = (string_params['verb'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Content-Encoding'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Content-Language'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Content-Length'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Content-MD5'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Content-Type'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Date'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['If-Modified-Since'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['If-Match'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['If-None-Match'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['If-Unmodified-Since'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Range'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['CanonicalizedHeaders']
                  + string_params['CanonicalizedResource'])


signed_string = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(base64.b64decode(storage_account_key), msg=string_to_sign.encode('utf-8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()).decode()
authHV= {'SharedKey ' + storage_account_name + ':' + signed_string}

headers = {
    'x-ms-date' : request_time,
    'x-ms-version' : api_version,
    'Authorization' : authHV
}


url = ('http://localhost:10000/' + storage_account_name + '?comp=list')
#
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)

print(r.content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're 2 errors in your code:

1.In 'CanonicalizedResource', you should use `'\ncomp:list'` instead of `'\ncomp=ist'`

2.For variable `authHV`, you should define it as `authHV=('SharedKey ' + storage_account_name + ':' + signed_string)`

And also remember `import requests` module.

Please use the code below, it works at my side:

```
import requests
import datetime
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

storage_account_name = 'devstoreaccount1'
storage_account_key = 'Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw=='
#api_version = '2016-05-31'
api_version = '2017-04-17'
request_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')

string_params = {
    'verb': 'GET',
    'Content-Encoding': '',
    'Content-Language': '',
    'Content-Length': '',
    'Content-MD5': '',
    'Content-Type': '',
    'Date': '',
    'If-Modified-Since': '',
    'If-Match': '',
    'If-None-Match': '',
    'If-Unmodified-Since': '',
    'Range': '',
    'CanonicalizedHeaders': 'x-ms-date:' + request_time + '\nx-ms-version:' + api_version + '\n',
    'CanonicalizedResource': '/' + storage_account_name +'/'+storage_account_name + '\ncomp:list' #note, it should be '\ncomp:list', no '/'
}

string_to_sign = (string_params['verb'] + '\n' 
                  + string_params['Content-Encoding'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Content-Language'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Content-Length'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Content-MD5'] + '\n' 
                  + string_params['Content-Type'] + '\n' 
                  + string_params['Date'] + '\n' 
                  + string_params['If-Modified-Since'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['If-Match'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['If-None-Match'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['If-Unmodified-Since'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Range'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['CanonicalizedHeaders']
                  + string_params['CanonicalizedResource'])

signed_string = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(base64.b64decode(storage_account_key), msg=string_to_sign.encode('utf-8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()).decode()

headers = {
    'x-ms-date' : request_time,
    'x-ms-version' : api_version,
    'Authorization' : ('SharedKey ' + storage_account_name + ':' + signed_string)
}

url = ('http://127.0.0.1:10000/' + storage_account_name + '?comp=list')

r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)

print(r.status_code)
print(r.content)
```

**The test result as below:**

[image]

Comment: WOW thank you I cant believe ```comp=list !=comp:list``` in the CanonicalizedResource part such a tiny error my bad