# Reading tdms files with python and notebook på Azure

Tags: python

I am trying to read tdms files from one Azure data lake to another and convert them to parquet at the same time. I managed to install the package nptdms in Azure Data Factory and ran the code line below

1. from nptdms import TdmsFile

But I don't know how to give value path_to_file in the second code line or the third.
2. tdms_file = TdmsFile.read("path_to_file.tdms")
Every files in Azure data lake has an URL as file path in this format:
https://xxxyyy.blob.core.windows.net/name_of_file.tdms

It did not work. I believe that the nptdms package was just written for on-premises and it does not work with cloud syntax

I wonder anyone has and can share experience with reading tdms.files in Azure platform.

Comment: You have to use `urllib.request.urlopen` to access urls.

Comment: Hi @NizamMohamed, Many thanks for your help. How would you rewrite my 
tdms_file = TdmsFile.read("path_to_file.tdms") 
when my file has an URL in Azure as followed: https://xxxyyy.blob.core.windows.net/name_of_file.tdms? Have you made it work with nptdms package?

Answer (score 0):

Since the files may be bigger in size, you should download and store it in a temporary file so that you can pass the file path to `TdmsFile.open` or `TdmsFile.read`.

`tmp_file.name` is its path here.

```
from shutil import copyfileobj
from urllib.request import urlopen
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from nptdms import TdmsFile


with urlopen('http://www-personal.acfr.usyd.edu.au/zubizarreta/f/exampleMeasurements.tdms') as response:
    with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as tmp_file:
        copyfileobj(response, tmp_file)

tdms_file = TdmsFile.open(tmp_file.name)


for group in tdms_file.groups():
    group_name = group.name
    print(f'Group name: {group_name}')
    for channel in group.channels():
        channel_name = channel.name
        print(f'Channel name: {channel_name}')
```

Comment: Hi Nizam,
I tested your code and it worked as you said. But my problem was that my files are in a fileshare on Azure and when I tried it with the URL I got from the fileshare

with urlopen('https://storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net/fileshare/xxxx.tdms') as response:
    with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as tmp_file:
        copyfileobj(response, tmp_file)

It failed with the following message:
HTTP Error 400: The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
Have you tried it with Azure fileshare? What did I do wrong? Have you a better way to do it?

Comment: Azure file share needs authentication. You'd better use Python SDK. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49874783/cant-connect-to-azure-file-service-rest-api-by-python